# Cannot find -Ifreeglut

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, freeglut

I am working on Glut Project in Code::Blocks. I have Freeglut.dll in windows folder in C Drive. I have also copied this file in sysWOW64 (as i am using windows 10). But it still gives the error mentioned in the pictures bellow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: **_Never(!)_**  copy any files into the Windows directories. Only pain and despair await you down that path. If your program requires particular nonstandard DLLs, copy them into the directory your program's `.EXE` resides in.

Comment: It does not work !

Comment: BDL gave you the answer to your problem. I just pointed out that you should *never* place stuff in the Windows directories; that doesn't solve your problem at hand, but *avoids* further problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The linker does not find `Freeglut.lib`. Most probably you missed to add the path to the lib directory to the linker options. I don't know how to do this in Code::Blocks, but in general you have to add these additional library directories using the `-L<DIR>` switch for the linker.